# How to take path from variable Bash

Tags: bash

I can't get path from variable in bash. How do it correct?
For example:

```
my@PC:~$ a="~/.bashrc"
my@PC:~$ cat $a
cat: ~/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

didn't work, but

```
cat .bashrc
```

and

```
cat ".bashrc"
```

Works well.

---

Here is right answer from fedorqui

```
cat $(eval echo $a)
```

Comment: You can try `cat $(eval echo $a)`

Comment: `eval` is *not* recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the issue is that the tilde is expanded to the home directory by the shell. When you store it in a variable, the tilde is not expanded and cat looks for a file .bashrc in the folder ~ (rather than your home directory)

There are two ways around the issue: the proposed eval, and using $HOME:

```
a="$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Comment: You could also use `a=~/".bashrc"` or even `a=~/.bashrc` -- as long as the `~` is outside the quotes it'll be expanded (unlike `$variable`, which is expanded even inside double-quotes).